# VB setFocus after Typing in Textbox without losing it

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a login screen where I set the focus to be on the `password` textbox so that the user can start typing their password without clicking anything.

I want to set the focus to the `login` button as soon as a character is typed into the `password` textbox so that the user can just hit Enter when they're done typing in the password.

I don't want to lose focus on the `password textbox`, but I want the login button to be highlighted so that you can hit Enter.

Right now I have to hit Tab, then Enter for this to work.

Comment: Is this VB.NET or VBA?  If VB.NET, WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I'm using VBA to code this. Right now I have to hit Enter twice. First time to focus on the button then a second time for it to actually go through and login. I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Went to the Property Sheet for the Login button and the Default property was set to No. Changed it to Yes and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [Form.Accept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) Property of your **Form** to the Button's Name:

> Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user
>   presses the ENTER key.

Then when the user is done entering their password and hits enter your button will be clicked automatically for them.

Comment: that didn't work for me. I'm not sure why I am having this problem